# Any way to do EXACTLY the same Gmail search via APIs as you can via filters/UI? (the normal APIs I found don't behave the same)

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

So I discovered that the queries specified in [`GmailApp.search`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery) and [`Gmail.Users.Messages.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) don't behave the same way as in the UI or as in Gmail filters.

Specifically, the API doesn't seem to engage in **word stemming**. So searching for something like `subject:job` also matches `jobs` in the UI and in filters, but not in the API.

Is there a workaround for this so I can get exactly the same behavior?
(I also tried IMAP, but that didn't work either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional q parameter that you can send in the body of a request using `Users.messages: list` supports the same search string query format as the [Gmail web UI](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list), so it looks like this is behaviour that shouldn't be happening.

I've submitted this as an issue to Goggle Issue Tracker, which you can follow [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135239305) and give a star to keep up-to-date with updates.

Comment: Would you happen to know how long they usually take to fix these sorts of bugs? Like a few weeks, months, years...?